# Azure App Insights: Can a period or grain of more than 48 hours be used in Alert Queries?

Tags: azure-application-insights

[image]We are implementing Azure App Insights Alerts and on the UI of an instance the max period or grain is 48 hours. Does that mean i can't do a query over a period of 1 week? The UI implies max 48 hours but i see examples where the alert query shows a freely choos-able time period.

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 1):

I got a suggestion to do it in Logic Apps according this article where it seems you can do a bigger range than 48 hours?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps

according this query shown:

requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where success == "False"
| project name, operation_Id
| join ( exceptions
    | project problemId, outerMessage, operation_Id
) on operation_Id
| evaluate autocluster()

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. This is by design. Details please refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22637#issuecomment-455050406):

> Max time period is limited to 48 hours and frequency to 24 hours; you
>   can't exceed either.
>
> This is done to prevent abuse of Azure Monitor by miscreants pushing
>   queries fetching large swaths of data and breaking analytics
>   performance for everyone.